# PlatformException on Android while trying to sign in with Google using firebase_auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I was trying to sign in with my google account on my phone using firebase_auth and just after I select my Google account, this error occurs.
I am using the following plugins:

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^2.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3
```

I have created a Firebase project. 
Registered my android app. 
Added SHA-1
Made all changes to both build.gradle files.
google-services.json file is also in place.

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String name = '';

  Future signIn() async {
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    setState(() {
      name = user.displayName;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$name',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: signIn,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
[+3146 ms] E/flutter (13503): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception:
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)
```

Comment: Did you updated your google play services ? Does your emulator has Google Play ?

Comment: I am running it on my Android Device. Google Play Services is present and configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was actually quite simple. All I had to was add a Support email in the Firebase Project settings. Thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33303#issuecomment-497587066). Also, this has been updated in the officials docs now, at https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth